# How to assign multiple key combinations to `evil-escape-key-sequence` in spacemacs?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, spacemacs

I'd like to assign multiple key combinations that would exit vim insert mode in spacemacs. I tried:

`(setq-default evil-escape-key-sequence "fj" "jf" "fd" "df")`

But only the first one works. How should I do it properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be set with the `evil-escape-unordered-key-sequence` variable:
`SPC SPC` `customize-variable` `RET` `evil-escape-unordered-key-sequence`, then hit `Toggle`, then hit `Apply and Save`.

See `SPC h d v` `evil-escape-unordered-key-sequence` for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Currently you can't assign multiple keys to `evil-escape-key-sequence` but there is simple workaround to achieve the same result: ([source](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/5445)):

1. add `key-chord` to `dotspacemacs-additional-packages`
2. in dotspace/user-config () add

   ```lisp
   (key-chord-mode 1)
   (key-chord-define evil-insert-state-map "fd" 'evil-escape)
   ```
3. restart spacemacs

And now both combinations, default (`df / fd`) and new (`fj / jf`) work.